# Merging bitbucket pull request via API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

According to [Bitbucket API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.15.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45622371767360), I should be able to merge a pull request with POST to this url:

```
https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectkey}/repos/{repositoryslug}/pull-requests/{pullrequestid}/merge?version
```

Yet, whenever I try it, I receive response `409 Conflict` and in the response, it contains this:

```
"message": "You are attempting to modify a pull request based on out-of-date information.",
"currentVersion": 0,
"expectedVersion": -1,
```

I tried passing `0` as the version number, `-1` as the version number, omit version number altogether - the result is always the same. How can I get it to merge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, atlassian API documentation was a bit wrong (or unclear). I was doing everything correctly, but the version number needs to be passed differently. According to the docs, the format is

```
https://.../merge?version
```

Whereas the correct format is

```
https://.../merge?version=<version>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `version` value should be the value from the response of the `GET` request as documented [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.15.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45622371701008)

In addition you can check if the pull request can be merged by making a `GET` [request](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.15.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45622371781696) to the `merge` endpoint

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already doing this. See my own answer for the solution.